# Identify version of C file

Tags: c, gcc, c99, ctags, c11

For a project I need to find if a c file has code that requires >=C11 or C99 compiler.  Can this be done with gcc, or ctags?

Basically I need to identify the minimum version of compiler required to compile the file.  I have tried different tools including ctags etc.

Comment: You could write a shellscript/batch file that tries `gcc -std=c90` Did it work? If not, try `gcc -std=c99`. Then C11.

Comment: @Lundin's suggestion or something substantially equivalent is the only option I see.  Solving the problem requires attempting to interpret the given source according to various language standards, and a program that performs that job (one standard at a time) is what a compiler *is*.  Do note, however, that there is code that will be accepted by various C compilers that does not conform to *any* of the language standards.

Comment: I'd add a `-pedantic-errors` and maybe a `-Wall` to the compile options.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -- -std= Makefile`

ctags: no way

If you are looking for something smarter... bad luck.